# Losing Part of Image When Using DrawImage on Panel

Tags: c++, winforms

I am making a WinForms app where HD images (1920 x 1080) are displayed on a panel control.  The images are actually from an HD webcam.  The panels are smaller (240 x 135) than the images and I am having a problem getting the images to resize and display in the panels.  Sometimes I just crash outright and other times the image is not resized.

The images are bitmaps and I am redrawing them in the Paint event for the control.

Here is the code for the Paint event handler.

```
void Cam0Panel_Paint( Object^ /*sender*/, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^ e )
{
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = ImageWinArray[CHANNEL_SELECT0];
    Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;

    g->InterpolationMode = System::Drawing::Drawing2D::InterpolationMode::Bilinear;
    g->CompositingMode = System::Drawing::Drawing2D::CompositingMode::SourceCopy;
    g->DrawImage(b,System::Drawing::Rectangle(0,0,Cam0Panel->Right,Cam0Panel->Bottom));
}
```

I am specifying the top, left point in the panel itself (0,0) and for the image to be resized to the panel size.  For some reason not working.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but the source image data is presumably being updated asynchronously by the camera - maybe you need to lock it in some way before you can render it.

Comment: That would be a good guess but it is not what is happening.  First, the images are quickly copied to a data structure that prevents the images from being overwritten.  Second, the fact that I do see images (though not resized properly) most of the time means that it is something about the drawimage call itself.